# Create an array of names from a string of text scraped from a website

Tags: html, css, regex, ruby

My big issue with this query is trying to correctly format each full name as individual strings in an array.

Not sure if it's necessary but a bit of background: this is for a personal project that I'm working on and I'm trying to grab the names of baseball players from their teams website through "baseball-reference.com". The code below is meant to grab the list of players from the active 40 man roster and list an array of the players for the selected team, in this case the Chicago Cubs (the team in the 4th array spot).

```
require 'open-uri'

site = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(site))


@teams = page.css(".row_summable").css("tbody tr").css(".left").css("a")

def team_links
  @teams.map do |team|
    team["href"].delete_prefix('/teams')
  end
end

def team_names
  @teams.map do |team|
    team.text
  end
end

team_page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(site + team_links[4]))

player_list = []
player_list.push(team_page.css(".grouplist").text.split.each_slice(2).map{|a|a.join ' '})

puts player_list
```

This is what I have right now and the issue is that it's slicing every two words so if someone has a third part of their name (ex: Jr.) the Array comes back with the names out of order (starting with wherever the third name came into play).

Not sure if this makes sense or has been answered before but I searched and tried to apply a ton of different regex formulas without luck. Above is the closest I've come so something that I'm looking for but won't work for any team with one player (let alone multiple) that has a third name.

Here is what it currently outputs for the Cubs:

```
Jason Adam
Adbert Alzolay
Javier Baez
David Bote
Kris Bryant
Victor Caratini
Willson Contreras
Yu Darvish
Phil Ervin
Ian Happ
Kyle Hendricks
Jason Heyward
Nico Hoerner
Jonathan Holder
Craig Kimbrel
Dillon Maples
Brailyn Marquez
Tyson Miller
Alec Mills
James Norwood
Colin Rea
Anthony Rizzo
Kyle Ryan
Max Schrock
Robert Stock
Duane Underwood
Jr. Ildemaro
Vargas Rowan
Wick Brad
Wieck Dan
Winkler
```

How I'd like it to display is:

```
Jason Adam
Adbert Alzolay
Javier Baez
David Bote
Kris Bryant
Victor Caratini
Willson Contreras
Yu Darvish
Phil Ervin
Ian Happ
Kyle Hendricks
Jason Heyward
Nico Hoerner
Jonathan Holder
Craig Kimbrel
Dillon Maples
Brailyn Marquez
Tyson Miller
Alec Mills
James Norwood
Colin Rea
Anthony Rizzo
Kyle Ryan
Max Schrock
Robert Stock
Duane Underwood Jr. 
Ildemaro Vargas 
Rowan Wick 
Brad Wieck 
Dan Winkler
```

Obviously right now the issue is that it's breaking the output every two words, so "Jr." is seen as a new first name, instead of a third part of a name.

Comment: Please provide a valid sample of your returned data, and a valid example of a completed transformation into the data structure you want.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Todd, I added the current output as well as a sample of what I'd like the output to look like. I'm new to this- thank you for help!

Comment: You need to post a valid section of the raw JSON or HTML you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just run your code, looked at the source and found a possible solution.  If you're willing to take advantage of the fact that the players are all in "list item" `<li>` tags, you should be able to do the following:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

site = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(site + "teams/"))

@teams = page.css(".row_summable").css("tbody tr").css(".left").css("a")

def team_links
  @teams.map do |team|
    team["href"]
  end
end

team_page = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open(site + team_links[4]))

player_list = team_page.css(".grouplist").css("li").map(&:text)

puts player_list
```

The change is in extracting all the list items as separate objects and converting them to text afterwards.

Comment: This was awesome - tried upvoting but since I'm too new it won't let me. Thanks so much for your help! (And sorry for the delayed response!!!)

Comment: @bleeblah2424 no probs mate.  glad it helped